# python struct module - odd values when unpacking

Tags: python, struct, int

I'm trying to get the integer value for b'\x00\x00\x00\x01', which should be 1 I assume.

I've tried several things to get this value of '1', but instead I get really high numbers.

This is what I tried:

```
import struct
from struct import *

#I had 4 int values:
byte1 = 0
byte2 = 0
byte3 = 0
byte4 = 1

#I packed each to one byte (seems weird, one int to 1 byte - so is this correct?)
byte1 = struct.pack('b', byte1) #returns b'\x00'
byte2 = struct.pack('b', byte2)
byte3 = struct.pack('b', byte3)
byte4 = struct.pack('b', byte4) #returns b'\x01'

#Now i place all those bytes in one container
con = byte1+byte2+byte3+byte4 #returns b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'

#hmm ..returns 4 - so seems alright?
len(con) 

#tried several things:
struct.unpack('I', con) #unsigned int - returns 16777216 (what!?)
struct.unpack('i', con) #signed int - returns the same as above
unpack('I', con) #same ..
```

My question; Am I doing something wrong? Am I understanding something wrong?
Can anyone please explain to me why it isn't just showing '(1,)' ?

If there's another way to get the int rep. please let me know too.

Thank you kindly for reading, and your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You interpret the result as little endian, but you should interpret it as big endian.  Try

```
>>> con = b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
>>> struct.unpack('>i', con)
(1,)
```

to use the correct [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Perfect, this works indeed. But I thought little endian starts reading from the right. Anyhow, thanks alot.

Comment: Little endian is the "reversed" one where the most significant byte comes last.

Comment: @joey: `<opinionated>` Little endian is the One True Endianness.  It puts bits 0-7 in byte 0, bits 8-15 in byte 1 and so on.  Big endian was a historical mistake that resulted from the fact that we usually write numbers "in reverse", so that bit 0 comes in the last place. `</opinionated>`